# Solving Linear equation for mass spring system

Tags: matlab, math, equation

I have an array

```
X=[ 0.1000    0.0844    0.0434   -0.0090   -0.0559   -0.0831   -0.0832   -0.0574   -0.0152    0.029]
```

which shows the position. The time array with respect to that position is

```
T= [0    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000]
```

And I have the mass spring equation `mx’’ + c x’ + kx = 0`, where `x’’` is the double derivative of x, which I have found by using `dx=diff(x.2)` and `dt2=diff(t,2)`, and `x’` is found by `dx=diff(x)`  and `dt=(diff)`.

The problem is I have implemented the code to find the value of `c` and `k` in the equation using `A=x\b`.

I have implemented the code by using `xx=dx./dt;   xx2=dx2./dt2;`

The values obtained using the formula `A=x\b`  are `Nan` and `Nan` for `c` and `k`, because my `dt2=diff(t,2)` comes out to be zero. I have even added zeros to make the size equal for `xx` and `xx2`, but what can I do to make the size equal apart from padding with zeros, since I think that's causing a lot of issues.

I there a way I can like interpolate and get the sizes equal for the `diff`, since `diff` is reducing the size by n-1, correct? And what can be done about `dt2`: is it fine or it should be `dt2=dt^.2`, since it's coming out to be all zero.

Below is my code.

```
x=[ 0.1000    0.0844    0.0434   -0.0090   -0.0559   -0.0831   -0.0832   -0.0574   -0.0152    0.029]';
t= [0    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000]';  
dx=diff(x);
dt=diff(t);
dx2=diff(x,2);
dt2=diff(t,2); % this comes out zero
xx=dx./dt;

xx2=dx2./dt2;
% padding zeros to make size equal

xx2=padarray(xx2,size(x)-size(xx2),'post');
xx=padarray(xx,size(x)-size(xx),'post');
mass=100;
gh=horzcat(xx,x);
A=gh\(m*xx2)
```

Comment: ehm, your `xx2 = diff(x,2) ./ diff(t,2)` is embarrassing. You should review the definition of second time derivative and its approximation by means of finite differences.

Answer (score 0):

Just c and k?  What about m?  Don't you need that, too?

This is a homogeneous ODE.  The array tells you what the initial displacement is at time zero, but what about velocity?  You need two initial conditions.  Are you going to assume that velocity is zero at the start as well?  Or will you choose to calculate a first difference based on the two points you have?

I'd recommend plotting the values, seeing what they look like, and trying to take an educated guess on the constants based on what you observe.  You know the closed form solution for this ODE; you might be able to tell what the values should be based on the data you're given.

After having done that, I'd recommend writing a matrix solution for the unknowns based on calculated differences at a number of points.  That'll turn the problem into a least squares solution for the constants.  It might be that one set of constants won't satisfy the equation at every point in time.

Another approach would be to take an FFT of the data and compare that to a solution in the frequency domain.